# What's wrong with my solution for $2\csc^{2}x+\cot x-3=0$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to solve the equation $2\csc^2 x+\cot x-3=0$ for $0 \le x \le 2\pi$. While I know that the identity $1+\cot^2 x=\csc^2 x$ can be used to solve this problem, I attempted to solve it using an unconventional approach. Here are the steps I took:

$2\csc^{2}x+\cot x-3=0$

$\frac{2}{\sin^2x}+\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}-3=0$

$2+\cos x\sin x-3\sin^2x=0,x\neq 0$

$2\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}\sin x-3\sin^2x=0$

Then, I substituted $u=\sin x$ to get $10u^4-13u^2+4=0$, which has four solutions: $u=\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, -\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}, -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. This leads to eight solutions for $x:1.107,2.035,\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4},5.176,4.248$

I had substituted $\sin x$ as $\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$ and got the same 8 solutions for $x$.

However, when I checked my answer using a calculator, only $1.107,\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4},4.248$ were correct. The other four solutions gave me either $2$ or $-1$. Can someone help me understand where I went wrong?

Comment: $\cos x$ is not always equal to $\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}.$ It may be $-\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}.$

Comment: $\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}=\sqrt{\cos^2x}=|\cos x|$

Comment: Thanks! I did consider the possibility of this. But I thought this could be neglected as I will be squaring $\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$ later down the line while doing the algebra.

Comment: It's precisely the squaring the one which introduce the false solutions, because in general  $a=b\nLeftrightarrow a^2=b^2$

Comment: $\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}=\frac{3\sin^2x-2}{\sin x}$ is equivalent to $|\cos x|=\frac{3\sin^2x-2}{\sin x}.$ It does not imply $\cos x=\frac{3\sin^2x-2}{\sin x}.$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Evaluate+2Power%5BCsc%5Bx%5D%2C2%5D%2B+Cot%5Bx%5D-3%3D0 , For anyone who wants to refer to calculator for verification.

Answer (score 2):

As commented above, your equation $\cos x=3\sin x-\frac2{\sin x}$ is not equivalent to $\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}=3\sin x-\frac2{\sin x}$ i.e. (after substitution $u=\sin x$ and resolution) to your final
$$\sin x\in\left\{\pm\frac2{\sqrt5},\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}\right\}\tag{*}$$

Instead, it is equivalent to

- either
  $$\cos x>0\quad\text{and}\quad3\sin x>\frac2{\sin x}\quad\text{and}\quad (*),$$ i.e. $$\cos x>0\quad\text{and}\quad\sin x\in\left\{\frac2{\sqrt5},-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right\},$$
  i.e.
  $$x\in\left\{\arcsin\frac2{\sqrt5},\frac{7\pi}4\right\}$$
- or
  $$\cos x<0\quad\text{and}\quad3\sin x<\frac2{\sin x}\quad\text{and}\quad (*),$$ i.e. $$\cos x<0\quad\text{and}\quad\sin x\in\left\{-\frac2{\sqrt5},\frac1{\sqrt2}\right\},$$
  i.e.
  $$x\in\left\{\pi+\arcsin\frac2{\sqrt5},\frac{3\pi}4\right\}.$$

Comment: But for x $\in [0,2π]$
$\begin{gather*} 
\\ cos(x)>0 \forall x \in [0,π/2] \cup [3π/2,2π]\\
\therefore sin(x) \in [-1,1]\\
\textrm{so all 4 solutions should be considered right?}
\end{gather*}$

Comment: No @XZCY: in the 1st case $\cos x>0,$ only the $2$ solutions I indicated because (as detailed in my answer) in that case $3\sin x-\frac2{\sin x}$ must also be $>0$ (since we want it to be equal to $\cos x,$ not to $-\cos x$), which discards two of the four values of $(*)$.

Answer (score -1):

Write the equation as $2\frac{\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x}+\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}-3=0$

Comment: This does not answer the question ("Can someone help me understand where I went wrong?").

Comment: But this is much easier way to solve the equation.

Comment: @kmitov That is not the issue.